# MySQL storage engine dilemma

Tags: php, mysql

There are two MySQL database features that I want to use in my application. The first is FULL-TEXT-SEARCH and TRANSACTIONS.

Now, the dilemma here is that I cannot get this feature in one storage engine. It's either I use MyIsam (which has the FULL-TEXT-SEARCH feature) or I use InnoDB (which supports the TRANSACTION feature). I can't have both.

My question is, is there anyway I can have both features in my application before I am forced to make a choice between the two storage engines.

Comment: You can use something like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to index and search any MySQL database. You could then use InnoDB.

Comment: Okay. That's lucene right. I guessed that wud be my only option. Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: just use innodb. trust the cache which does most of the work, you won't need full text search.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan full-text search has nothing to do with speed. It's a feature that you can't get with standard SQL queries.

Comment: @MichaelMior: Exactly. Unless you (utterly) normalize your text columns into word (or even character) columns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possible workarounds:

1. Use Sphinx or Solr or some other external text search engine for your text searches and use InnoDB engine.
2. Write your own search code - and use InnoDB. This is not really an option, unless you search needs are limited or your budget is huge.
3. Use both engines, MyISAM and InnoDB. Keep the columns you want to be full-text searching in MyISAM and the rest in InnoDB. This will be risky as the data in MyISAM will not be transaction safe.
4. Use both engines, MyISAM and InnoDB. Keep all data in InnoDB and duplicate the columns you want to be full-text searching in MyISAM. This will need some mechanism (triggers) for the data duplication.
5. Wait for the version of MySQL where full-text search will be supported by InnoDB or other transactional engine.
6. (Option 4) but use MariaDB (a MySQL fork) which has "crash-safe" (but still not transaction-safe) full text indexes: [When-will-transactional-fulltext-indexes-be-ready?](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/when-will-transactional-fulltext-indexes-be-ready)
7. Use other RDBMS like PostgreSQL that has full-text support in transactional engine.

Comment: +1 Nice overview. I've had success with option 4 in a case where the fulltext requirement is localized to a few columns.

Comment: +1, btw, does option 5 have a projected date or are you just speculating?

Comment: @AndrewHeath: No, I have no idea about a projected date. You may ask at the MySQL (InnoDB) forum or at the MariaDB forum.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to perform transactions and full-text against a single table in MySQL, you have a few options.  But really the salient point to take away from this entire discussion is that databases are not good at doing full-text search to begin with (especially MySQL!) and ideally you want to offload this work to a component that is better at performing this type of task.

**Option 1:**

Create one table that you need to do the transaction against as InnoDB and then create another "mirror" table that is MyISAM that you can do full-text search against. You can keep the data in sync through the use of a trigger on the InnoDB table. Sort of a hack but it will work.

**Option 3:**

Take a look at a 3rd party full-text engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  This way you can focus on designing your database to be optimal at querying data and not forcing it to do text search as well.

**Option 3:**

You can choose to go with a different database server that supports transactions and full-text search at the same time, such as SQL Server.

Hope this give you some clarity.

Enjoy!

Comment: using a search engine as opposed to full-text indexes are totally different approaches - both have their benefits and drawbacks. read on here for a nice comparison of Lucene vs. MySQL full-text.. may fit well on other search engines vs. other database engines: http://jayant7k.blogspot.com/2006/05/mysql-fulltext-search-versus-lucene.html

Answer (score 3):

The MyISAM full-text index probably isn't as good as you think. It works ok(ish) on small data, but is lousy on bigger data.

In MySQL 5.6 we may have full-text on InnoDB, however it still does not support most of the features that a real full-text search engine would have.

Answer (score 2):

there is no way to have both in the same database engine, these are the constraints given by the design how MySQL works. You can not change physics. ;-)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

when you're still in design phase, you may also consider using another SQL implmentation for your project which supports both in the same engine. Postgres for example does.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Why_PostgreSQL_Instead_of_MySQL_2009#Transactions_and_the_Database_Engine_Core

Comment: Thanks Kaii... Postgre here I come :).

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with physics, but here's a faster-than-light neutrino for you: http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/innodb-fts-performance/

Comment: @Michael: sorry, forgot the smiley alongside "physics". i fixed that. nice to read innodb soon supports full-text, but we still have to wait until this is available in the mysql packages of major distributions.

Comment: Not ready for product any time soon, but my point is that it's not impossible :) (Although you don't have to wait for distributions to include MySQL packages.)

Answer (score 1):

One another option is to use MySQL's support for replication:

For example you can setup master server with InnoDB storage engine. Then replicate to another read-only server with the MyISAM storage engine.

You can use almost any MySQL storage engine and there might be some that support better search features than MyISAM for some use cases.