# Changing storage engine of table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Currently the storage type of table is innodb , i want to add full text search on the table which is only possible on  `MYISAM` engine.
I tried using the command => `alter table film engine = myisam;`
and got the error:

```
1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Help Please!!
Thanks.

Comment: Remove all foreign key constraints then. But you better create another table with your text field instead

Comment: You do not need to change those to MyIsam engine better to have one new MyIsam table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must find the tables in the database that refer to this table through a FK constraint:

Identify the foreign key constraints for the table. Either use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_in_db_film`\G;
```

or

```
USE db_of_film_table;
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'film'\G
```

afterwards execute the necessary statements

```
ALTER TABLE film DROP FOREIGN KEY `ibfk_something`;
```

until you drop all constraints (of course replace *ibfk_something* with your constraint names). After this you should be able to alter the table engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the table's engine to MyISAM without removing the Foreign Key constraints and thus losing integrity.

It would be better to use both engines, MyISAM and InnoDB. Keep all data in InnoDB and duplicate the table (or just the columns you want to be full-text searching) in MyISAM. This will need some mechanism (triggers) for the data duplication to be automated.

Other options here: [MySQL storage engine dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272917/mysql-storage-engine-dilemma/8273057#8273057)